# How can I correctly document a schema that uses a JsonConverter in NSwag?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We're using a technique similar to whats described here: [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n) to basically use a `JsonConverter` to allow us change the JSON output of our model:

```
public sealed record EntityFieldsModelWithValues(
    FieldDefinitionWithValues[] Fields
);

public record FieldDefinitionWithValues(
    FieldDefinition Definition, 
    [property:JsonConverter(typeof(AllowedValueConverter))]
    AllowedValue Value
);

public record AlowedValue(
    bool IsMultivalue,
    bool IsObject,
    List<object?> Values);
```

The converter lets us write different JSON depending upon the bool params, so if `IsMultivalue`, write an array, if we have only a single item, write an object if `IsObject` or a string otherwise:

```
"value" : "string",
"value" : "2023-10-23T15:00:00",
"value" : {
    "id": "id",
    "label": "label"
},
"value": [],
"value": {},
"value": ["string", "string"]
"value": [
    { "id": "id", "label": "label" },
    { "id": "id", "label": "label" }
]
```

Everything works fine but the OpenApi document only documents the `AllowedValue` which should really be internal as it doesn't match what the `JsonConverter` produces:

[image]

In OpenApi terms I guess I want to replace `AllowedValue` with an `anyOf` for each of supported outputs using variations of the main model?

```
"responses": {
  "200": {
    "description": "Returned when the required metadata fields and allowed values are retrieved.",
    "content": {
      "application/json": {
        "schema": {
          "anyOf": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/EntityFieldsModelWithValues"
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/EntityFieldsModelWithValues1"
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/EntityFieldsModelWithValues2"
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/EntityFieldsModelWithValues3"
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/EntityFieldsModelWithValues4"
          }       
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm a little unsure where to start, from my current investigations I need a custom `ISchemaProcessor` object to do this is that correct?